# calling react-expo react native professionals for third party library integration

Tags: react-native, webpack, babeljs, expo, babel-loader

I'm trying to integrate the react library called react-canvas-draw with expo.

the error in question is:

*Component Exception - View config getter callback for component 'canvas' must be a function (received 'undefined'). Make sure to start component names with a capital letter.*

[image]

I think its a babel config fix. converting es2015 to es7 or something then to react native code. I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

So I stopped using react-expo because it's a pain in the ass to configure all the settings with (Babel, es6, jest, eslint, etc & metro configs). I Generally know what all those packages do in layman's terms but I do not know anything with setting them up together and what goes where.

Instead I'm using `npx create-react-native-app` It comes pre-configured for what I'm doing and it has some neat feature like hot-reloading so it's just as fast in development. It's not as helpful as expo with ease of use with ios and android setup and exports but I can manage the configurations on my own.